# 401 with pouchdb authentication on put

Tags: authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

Using the `apache/couchdb:2` docker image. I've added a user in couchdb (bloggs) and a database (notes) and added the user to the database, using Fauxton.

Then using pouchdb-authentication I've tried:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://couchdb.korea.lan:5984/notes', {skip_setup: true});
db.logIn('bloggs', 'mypassword').then(function() {
  db.put(doc);
});
```

The login succeeds, I can do a `console.log()` or logout at that point. But the `db.put()` call fails with a 401:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not authorized to access this db."}
```

The container log output shows the username if I do a db.logout() but the db.put() says "undefined" where the username appears on the logout.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, looks like a bug.

I was just using the latest pouchdb version on a CDN. Rolling back from 7.0.0 to 6.4.3 has fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for this I thought I was going crazy not being able to work out the auth on Pouch 7.0.0